# Static keyword in an array function parameter declaration

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, language-lawyer, x86-64

Here is the explanation of what it means 6.7.6.3/7:

> If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array
>   type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.

It is not quite clear what it means. I ran the following example:

`main.c`

```
#include "func.h"

int main(void){
    char test[4] = "123";
    printf("%c\n", test_func(2, test));
}
```

And 2 different implementations of the `test_func`:

1. static version

`func.h`

```
char test_func(size_t idx, const char[const static 4]);
```

`func.c`

```
char test_func(size_t idx, const char arr[const static 4]){
    return arr[idx];
}
```

2. non-static version

`func.h`

```
char test_func(size_t idx, const char[const 4]);
```

`func.c`

```
char test_func(size_t idx, const char arr[const 4]){
    return arr[idx];
}
```

I checked the assembly code compiled with `gcc 7.4.0 -O3` of the function in both of the cases and it turned out to be completely identical:

Disassembly of the functions

```
(gdb) disas main
sub    rsp,0x18
mov    edi,0x2
lea    rsi,[rsp+0x4]
mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x4],0x333231
mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
xor    eax,eax
call   0x740 <test_func>
[...]

(gdb) disas test_func 
movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rsi+rdi*1]
ret
```

Can you give an example where the static keyword gives some benefits (or any differences at all) comparing to non-static counterpart?

Comment: I'd say the point is to catch smaller arguments so I would expect it to throw a compilation error for `test[3]` ... except it doesn't. Maybe the compiler is not required to provide diagnostic or just `gcc` doesn't. `clang` does give a `warning: array argument is too small; contains 3 elements, callee requires at least 4 [-Warray-bounds]` PS: has nothing to do with assembly, it's a compilation time thing.

Comment: @Jester Just checked it in case of passing a smaller array. As you noted, adding `-Warray-bounds` to the compiler options does not give any warning. Maybe this is a gcc bug... ?

Comment: It's a bug if the standard says diagnostic is required. I do not have access to the standard, so I can't tell. But even `clang` is only providing a warning.

Comment: For the code you have provided, the `static` keyword is useless anyway: The `static` keyword allows the compiler to assume that the array has *at least* as many elements as indicated, but *if you access an index*, the compiler may *also* assume the index is valid, because accessing out of bounds would be undefined behavior. To construct a case where the feature *could* be useful, the access would have to be to a known index, but *conditional* on some run-time predicate. However, the feature is apparently not used much, so `gcc` doesn't make use of the freedom it offers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example where `static` actually makes a difference:

```
unsigned foo(unsigned a[2])
{
    return a[0] ? a[0] * a[1] : 0;
}
```

clang (for x86-64, with -O3) compiles this to

```
foo:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        test    eax, eax
        je      .LBB0_1
        imul    eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

But after replacing the function parameter with `unsigned a[static 2]`, the result is simply

```
foo:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
        imul    eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        ret
```

The conditional branch is not necessary because `a[0] * a[1]` evaluates to the correct result whether a[0] is zero or not. But without the `static` keyword, the compiler cannot assume that a[1] can be accessed, and thus has to check a[0].

Currently only clang does this optimization; ICC and gcc produce the same code in both cases.

Comment: Nice job finding a case where a compiler actually *does* take advantage of the guarantee that the whole array is there and readable.  Last time I played with `[static size]` on Godbolt I only found missed optimizations, IIRC, but I don't remember what exactly I tried.

Comment: The interesting thing is that this seems like a case where actual code would *not* want to make that guarantee. It seems like the zero element is a sentinel at the end of a dynamic-sized array, and you normally wouldn't want to allow access past it.

Comment: And note that this probably wouldn't be a valid optimization for a `float` type, because of infinities and NaN. It takes advantage of a specific integer identity.

Comment: @PeterCordes So the point of `static` is to make sure we don't get out of bound in case we access an array member with an index lesser than the size expression value?

Comment: @St.Antario: yes, `foo(unsigned a[2])` is exactly equivalent to `foo(unsigned *a)`, and `a` is allowed to be pointing at the last int before an unmapped page.  `foo(unsigned a[static 2])` is different: the whole array object must be there.  (But `a`'s type inside the function is still `unsigned *a`, not an actual array so you can't use `sizeof(a)` to get the array size. https://godbolt.org/z/6fz3jQ)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't used much by compilers in my experience, but one use is that the compiler can assume that the (array decayed into pointer) parameter is not `NULL`.

Given this function, both gcc and clang (x86) produce identical machine code at `-O3`:

```
int func (int a[2])
{
  if(a)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Disassembly:

```
func:
        xor     eax, eax
        test    rdi, rdi
        setne   al
        ret
```

When changing the parameter to `int a[static 2]`, gcc gives the same output as before, but clang does a better job:

```
func: 
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

Since clang realizes that `a` can never be NULL, so it can skip the check.